# Change text field to a select and default value

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have found a piece of code in our website that I would like to change.

We would like our gender field to be a select option and default it a value from a users profile and then provide them the option of Male/Female.

Any advice on how I could change the below code to a select?

```
<label for="dbem_gender"><?php _e('Gender','buddypress');?></label>
<input type="text" name="dbem_gender" id="dbem_gender" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user_id,'dbem_gender',true); ?>" class="settings-input" <?php bp_form_field_attributes( 'gender' ); ?> >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="dbem_gender" name="dbem_gender">
<option <?php if (echo get_user_meta($user_id,'dbem_gender',true) == "Male" ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">Male</option>
<option <?php if (echo get_user_meta($user_id,'dbem_gender',true) == "Female" ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">Female</option>
</select>
```

I think you are looking for something like this.

Comment: Thank you . This looks like an option however it does not seem to work. I added a > after the option as well but that didn't help. I replaced the <input> section with your section however when I save the file the page no longer loads so I am assuming something is not working. Thanks for helping, any more tips?